# Any ideas why this bookmark script isn't working in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've been asked to figure out why a Javascript bookmark script isn't working in IE. Javascript isn't my forte so I'm a bit lost.

Any ideas?

The script in use is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/* Modified to support Opera */
function bookmarksite(title,url){
    if (window.sidebar) // firefox
        window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, "");
    else if(window.opera && window.print){ // opera
        var elem = document.createElement('a');
        elem.setAttribute('href',url);
        elem.setAttribute('title',title);
        elem.setAttribute('rel','sidebar');
        elem.click();
    } 
    else if(document.all)// ie
        window.external.AddFavorite(url, title);
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should get you started. [link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/addbook.htm)

Comment: @PhaniRahul That's - uh - exactly the same script that Dean used.

Comment: I was actually trying to say if there is anything else that went wrong. Because, I don't find anything wrong with the script.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: I guess if you've got a global variable named `sidebar` it won't ever get to the IE bit.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the AddFavorite method in IE8 has been restricted to only trigger with a user event,

not an automatic event like onload or onunload. try this

```
<a onclick = "bookmarksite('stackoverflow','http://stackoverflow.com')">BookMark</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working fine. Make sure the URL is a valid http url or else you will get an access denied error in IE (maybe other browser too though).

Comment: So it's working in IE for you then? It works fine in FF for me, but not in any version of IE

Comment: Yes, IE 7,8 and 9... http://jsfiddle.net/gWXGx/1/
Don't forget that it has to be called from a USER event.